SUM / makearray in Google Sheets from multiple array
I tried with sum, makearray as follows but it turned out to be incorrect.
How should I fix it?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvZerzOiW0vdewnfZT47WuU3TPlW15UHUSpvII1HE50/edit#gid=1044610848
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(H4:H20),COLUMNS(I3:N3),LAMBDA(r,c,

sum(
(B4:B29=index(I3:N3,c))*
(C4:C29=index(G4:G20,r))*
(D4:D29=index(H4:H20,r))*
(E4:E29))


))

get the right formula

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.


slight modification of adding arrayformula() to your existing sum condition:
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(H4:H20),COLUMNS(I3:N3),LAMBDA(r,c,
arrayformula(sum(
(B4:B29=index(I3:N3,c))*
(C4:C29=index(G4:G20,r))*
(D4:D29=index(H4:H20,r))*
(E4:E29)))))



you can also solely just use sumproduct in place of arrayformula(sum(
